# Problems with MongoDB + async await

Tags: javascript, mongodb, asynchronous, mongoose, async-await

I am currently working on a little JS game (node.js, socket.io) and I need to retrieve data from my MongoDB (currently using Mongoose). Getting the data itself seems not to be the problem since I can console log it.
The problem is the timing. I need the data before the programm continues running. I've tryed using async await, but I think I might still be using it wrong since It doesn't work.

**card.controller.js:**

```
exports.CRUD = {
    getCardById : async (id) => {
        try {
          let cards = await Card.find({number:id}).exec();
          return cards ;
        } catch (err) {
          return 'error occured';
        }
    }
}
```

**game.js:**

```
/* Code is within a normal function (not async) */

(async () => {
        game.card = await CRUD.getCardById(cardId - 1);
        console.log("Game-Card: ",game.card); // Data gets logged here, but only after it already returned game
})();

/*return game*/
```

Comment: "*Code is within a normal function*" - well you need to change that.

Comment: One of the problem with async is that it require its surround also to be asynchronous.